# Ansible SSH key mismatch

Tags: ansible

I wrote the following Ansible playbook:

```
---
- name: Create VLAN
  hosts: exos_device
  connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli
  vars:
    ansible_user: admin
    ansible_password: password
    ansible_network_os: community.network.exos
  tasks:
  - name: Create VLAN 4050
    community.network.exos_config:
      lines:
        - create vlan TESTVLAN tag 4050
      match: exact
      save_when: always
```

Where I'm trying to create a new vlan on an Extreme Networks machine (ExtremeXOS version 16.2.5.4). But when I execute it I keep getting the following error:

```
fatal: [10.12.2.10]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "ssh connection failed: ssh connect failed: kex error : no match for method server host key algo: server [ssh-rsa], client [rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256]",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error"
}
```

I think this error indicates that there is a mismatch between the SSH key algorithms that the client (Ansible controller) and the server (the EXOS machine) support.

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

I've already tried specifying an algorithm inside the ansible.cfg file like this:

```
[defaults]
inventory = inventory.ini
ssh_args = -oKexAlgorithms=ssh-rsa
```

But with no success.

Comment: I think it should be other way around ..client refer to your network device. mention any algorithm in ssh_args for example -> ssh_args = -oKexAlgorithms=rsa-sha2-512

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but that makes no difference. Error stays exactly the same

Comment: ..try configuring ssh-rsa on your network device

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea and almost have this right, but it's complaining about `HostKeyAlgorithms` not `KexAlgorithms`. Also, the SSH client would need to support ssh-rsa, which is the only thing the SSH server on the managed network device seems to support.

man 5 ssh_config search for Algorithm or ssh-rsa

```
ssh_args = -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
```

Your SSH client implementation (paramiko? libssh?) doesn't list ssh-rsa as supported, so it might not exist, or it might just need to be explicitly enabled. If not, then you might try the other SSH type by setting:

```
ansible_network_cli_ssh_type: libssh
```

Take a look at `network_cli` docs for other examples.